# Generate dynamic link with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please help me, I have this function in my main controller:

```js
$scope.link = function (demo) {
            var index = $scope.demos.findIndex((v) => v.id === demo.id)
            alert(index)
        }
```

instead of making an alert with the index, I would like it to take me to a link, example:

```js
if (index % 2 == 0) {
           take me to a link...'www.example.com'     
            }
```

how can i do this?

Comment: Using [`location.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace): `window.location.replace('https://www.example.com')`.

Comment: thanks a lot @DM